# Does Aquaman have Scales?

Tags: dc, comics, aquaman

In most pictures, Aquaman's torso is orange or golden or something close to that and it looks like it is scaled.  I know his origin has changed several times, but even in the first version, he was adapted to the sea in different ways (like having gills).

Is what we see that looks like scales over his arms and chest clothing that looks like scales, or is it scales?  And if he is scaled, why do they stop at his neck?

Comment: Don't the fish scale stop at the neck as well?

Comment: Do fish have necks?  But that still doesn't tell me if those are scales.

Comment: @DVK - Nah; partially because.. well... where is a fish neck?  They basically come from the skin, much like human hair does.  Also, there are multiple kinds. [Fish Scales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_scale)

Comment: @KeithHWeston - http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/does-majority-of-fish-lack-scales-on-their-heads

Comment: @DVK - I look forward to the results, but I don't think it's necessarily easy to spot from visual cues.  That's why I mention hair.. Most people don't think of humans as having hair on some place that they do.  It's a different order of hair, but it's there. (See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glabrous_skin#Glabrous_skin) Wikipedia article.) Other than where it mentions.. We're a hairy species. Even the proverbial 'Baby's Bottom' that smooth things are compared to is hairy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aquaman wears an orange [scale mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_armour) top. This article on [Aquaman in popular media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaman_in_popular_media#DC_animated_universe) from Wikipedia states (emphasis mine):

> He was drawn in the "classic" Aquaman appearance as having an *orange shirt*, green gloves, green pants with green boots, a gold belt with gold "A" insignia belt buckle, short hair, and a clean-shaven face.

[image: Aquaman appears standing over a fallen Green Lantern, with his trident at Green Lantern's throat. Green Lantern lies on wet, sea-washed rocks by a small pool, with another wave, behind Aquaman, poised to crash over him. In the background Batman lies prone, holding onto the rocks. Aquaman is wearing green pants and matching green elbow-length gloves, a thick gold belt and an orange shirt fashioned in the pattern of scales.]

It's not actually his skin, as in the '90s he went with a shirtless look.

[image: The cover of Aquaman vs. Justice League #16 shows Aquaman, left, fighting Wonder Woman. Wonder Woman is yelling as she prepares to throw a punch with her left hand. Her right hand is upraised, with a spark where she blocks Aquaman's left-hand appliance with her bracer. Aquaman is wearing light blue pants, with green scale-pattern insets on the tops of his thighs, and shoulder-and-arm armour on the right side of his otherwise bare torso.]

Answer (score 4):

No.  The golden orange scales are a shirt he wears.  They have tried other costumes as seen on this [Wikipedia page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Aquaman1_%281986%29.jpg)  The picture here comes from his [DC Wiki page](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Aquaman)

[image: Half-naked Aquaman]

Comment: Learn something new every day -- I didn't know there was a DC Wiki - I was looking in the Wikipedia.  Thanks!